# How to count the number of entries in two selects?

Tags: mysql

Semi-newbyism ahead: I need to do two selects and count the number of items in both of them. Here's a bad example of what I thought would work --

```
sum(
  select count(*) as count1 from users where name = 'John'
    union
  select count(*) as count1 from users where name = 'Mary'
) as theCount
```

(This is, as I said, a BAD example, since I could obviously write this as a single select with an appropriate WHERE clause.  In what I really have to do, the two things I have to do are such that I can't do them as a single select (or, at least, I haven't yet found a way to do them as a single select).

Anyway, I think what I'm trying to do is clear: the select-union-select bit returns a column containing the counts of the two selects; that part works fine.  I thought that wrapping them in a SUM() would get me what I wanted, but it's throwing a syntax error.  The right thing is probably trivial, but I just don't see it. Any thoughts out there?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For generic selects that you can't necessarily write with one where:

```
SELECT sum(count1) as totalcount FROM (
  select count(*) as count1 from users where name = 'John'
    union all
  select count(*) as count1 from users where name = 'Mary'
) as theCount
```

Comment: Right -- Jim, the point here is that MySQL doesn't know what you mean by `SUM` when you put it where you did. It is much happier if you `SELECT SUM`, because then it knows that you would like to actually see the sum!

Comment: I voted this up, since it's almost exactly what I was thinking, but I think you need to make it a `union all` in case the 2 counts are the same.

Answer (score -1):

```
select count(*) as count1 from users where name in ('John','Mary')
```

This is another alternative

```
select ( select count(*) as count1 from users where name = 'John')
+
( select count(*) as count1 from users where name = 'Mary') as total
```

Another possible solution:

```
select 
sum(if(name='John',1,0)) as tot_John,
sum(if(name='Mary',1,0)) as tot_Mary,
sum(if(name in ('John','Mary'),1,0)) as total
from users
```

Comment: I'd like to know the reason of downvote. His example doesn't require subquery.

Comment: See the original statement -- my example was simplified (and stated as such) to keep the posted code readable.  The queries I'm actually doing are much messier, and rule out the solution posted here.